# Databricks Flatten Read / Unpack JSON Array

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I'm not entirely sure of the correct term to used here, wherther its Json Unpacking or Json explode, or simply JSON flattening. However, I'm trying to read columns for a Nested JSON array in Databricks.

For example, I would like to pull at the customerId number 'cust5001, which looks like the following key/value pair

```
array
0: {"customerId": "cust5001", "orderDate": "2021-12-24 00.00.00.000", "orderDetails": [{"productId": "prd9001", "quantity": 2, "sequence": 1, "totalPrice": {"gross": 550, "net": 500, "tax": 50}}, {"productId": "prd9002", "quantity": 3, "sequence": 2, "totalPrice": {"gross": 300, "net": 240, "tax": 60}}], "orderId": "ord1001", "shipmentDetails": {"city": "Delhi", "country": "India", "postalCode": "110040", "state": "New Delhi", "street": "M.G.Road"}}
1: {"customerId": "cust5002", "orderDate": "2021-12-25 00.00.00.000", "orderDetails": [{"productId": "prd9001", "quantity": 1, "sequence": 1, "totalPrice": {"gross": 275, "net": 250, "tax": 25}}, {"productId": "prd9004", "quantity": 4, "sequence": 2, "totalPrice": {"gross": 1000, "net": 900, "tax": 100}}], "orderId": "ord1002", "shipmentDetails": {"city": "Mumbai", "country": "India", "postalCode": "400064", "state": "Maharastra", "street": "Malad"}}
```

If you take a look at the complete image below, I believe I need to explode the column 'datasets'l and then query "customerId":"cust5001"

[image]

To be totally straight, I would like to flatten the whole two rows, but if someone could show me how pull out "customerId":"cust5001", it would be start.

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Are you looking for just `SELECT explode(datasets)`?

Comment: Hi Kombajn, thanks for reaching out. The fact that you mentioned its not clear what I want means that other community are also unclear as to what I want. I am looking flatten the nested arrays. If that means SELECT explode(datasets), then yes please.

Comment: ok, so I tried the following ```test = spark.sql("""select get_json_object(datasets, '$.customerId') as customerId
                                           from newtable""")```

Comment: But I get the error: ```cannot resolve 'get_json_object(newtable.datasets, '$.customerId')' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires string type, however, 'newtable.datasets' is of array>>,orderId:string,shipmentDetails:struct>> type.; line 1 pos 7;
'Project [get_json_object(datasets#23009, $.customerId) AS customerId#23534]```

Comment: Any thoughts. Getting kind of frustrated

Comment: First explode, then parse JSON: `SELECT get_json_object(dataset, '$.customerId') FROM (SELECT explode(datasets) as dataset FROM newtable)`